# how to print a list inside a function without using append method

Tags: python

```
k=[]
def subject(a):
     
    for i in range(0,a):
        ele=int(input("number: "))
        k=ele
    print(k)
        
n=int(input("Enter numb of elements: "))
subject(n)
#print(k)
```

I am not able to print whole list, that user input, please help?

Comment: Please format your code, right now it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use `append`, you should initialize your list with `n` number of `0's` or `None`. Try this:

```
def subject(a):
    k = [0 for _ in range(a)]  # Initialise your list with 'n' number of 0's 
    for i in range(0,a):
        ele = int(input("number: "))
        k[i] = ele   # Filling the i'th index of list with user input 
    print(k)
        
n=int(input("Enter numb of elements: "))
subject(n)
#print(k)
```

Output:

```
Enter numb of elements: 
3
number: 
1
number: 
2
number: 
3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work just fine as well:

```
def subject(a):
    k=[]     
    for i in range(a):
        ele = int(input("number: "))
        k += [ele]
    print(k)
        
n = int(input("Enter numb of elements: "))
subject(n)
```

Comment: List concatenation like this is like list append but less efficient. `%timeit l = [] ; l.append(1)` gives `117 ns ± 1.33 ns per loop`, while `%timeit l = [] ; l += [1]` gives `145 ns ± 0.842 ns`.

Comment: Yes, I know it's functionally the same, just slightly less efficient~ But the whole idea of not using `append` is a silly one to begin with haha

Comment: Definitely a silly idea ! I mostly put this poor benchmark there as a reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate for append is by using "+" operand. However, I did with string
Try this too

```
def subject(a):
    string=""
    for i in range(a):
        string+=input()
        result=[int(x) for x in string]
    return result
n=int(input("Enter a number :")) 
print(subject(n))
```